# popup window not closing

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I have a popup window which should close during onLoad.
The script used is

```
<body onLoad="window.opener.findPersonResults('undefined');this.close()">
```

But it is not closing this popup. I want this to be closed as soon as it is loaded.

Comment: Why opening it at all?

Comment: Try `console.log(this);`. You will be amazed by the result. One of the reasons not to use inline event handlers if you do not know exactly how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `this.close()` with `window.close()`.